# Java If Statement

Tags: java

I have this if statement at the moment

```
        if(answer4val != ""){
```

And answer4val is defined here

```
        answer4val  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("answer4"));
```

Basicly if answer4val is empty from the database, which it is the if statement should not run. But it is!? I'm used to PHP so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Use `.equals` not `==`

Comment: @Erik: That would have been a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your particular case I would use...

```
if(answer4val.length() > 0){
```

and in the general case use...

```
if (!answer4val.equals(<stuff here>)) {
```

Remember, in Java `==` is a reference compare when talking about objects such as strings.

*[update] If needed, be sure to check for null first but in most cases you shouldn't have too since most frameworks provide a "defaulting" value instead of null.*

```
if(answer4val == null) { /* bail early */
```

Comment: `equals`, not `equal` (fixed)

Comment: I used you length solution and is now creating a nullpointer exception. I used if(answer4val.length() > 0){

Comment: @Max: null and empty are separate, you may need to test for null-ness first by using `if (answer4val != null && answer4val.length() > 0){`

Comment: @Max: The `NullPointerException` is occurring when the `length()` method on a `null` is being called. Therefore, `answer4val` appears to be `null`. Also, checking for an empty `String` is better performed with the `String.isEmpty` method, rather than checking with the `length()` method.

Comment: @Max: you can use `if(!"".equals(answer4val)) { ... }` to prevent NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `null` is not the same as `""`. The fact that you're getting a NullPointerException from using the `.equals` solution means that maybe you shouldn't be comparing with `""` - you can compare with `null` like this:

```
if(answer4val != null) {
```

However, you might *also* need to compare it with `""`, which you can do e.g. like this:

```
if(answer4val != null && !answer4val.equals ("")) {
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, that may or may not be the right approach.